# Sql - Selecionar primeiro e ultimo registro

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Possuo as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_lote
(
  id_lote integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_lote_seq'::regclass),
  ds_lote character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pktb_lote PRIMARY KEY (id_lote)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_lote_ticket
(
  id_lote_ticket integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_lote_ticket_seq'::regclass),
  id_lote integer,
  nr_quantidade numeric(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT pktb_lote_ticket PRIMARY KEY (id_lote_ticket),
  CONSTRAINT fk_tb_lote_ticket_tb_lote FOREIGN KEY (id_lote)
      REFERENCES tb_lote (id_lote) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
);

CREATE TABLE tb_processo
(
  id_processo integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_processo_seq'::regclass),
  id_lote_ticket integer,
  id_setor integer,
  dt_inicio timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT pktb_processo PRIMARY KEY (id_processo),
  CONSTRAINT fk_tb_processo_tb_lote_ticket FOREIGN KEY (id_lote_ticket)
      REFERENCES tb_lote_ticket (id_lote_ticket) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tb_processo_tb_setor FOREIGN KEY (id_setor)
      REFERENCES tb_setor (id_setor) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

E o relacionamento é, Cada lote tem N ticket e cada ticket tem 1 processo.

```
- Lote    1..N   Ticket
- Ticket  1..1   Processo
```

Gostaria de saber como realizar um SQL eficiente para saber a `dt_inicio` de cada lote em cada `Setor` e ao mesmo tempo a "`dt_final`".
A `dt_final` seria a `dt_inicio` do ultimo processo.

#### Sql Atual

```
SELECT 
    Lote.id_lote as "Lote.id_lote", 
    Setor.ds_setor as "Setor.ds_setor", 
    Setor.id_setor as "Setor.id_setor",
    (
        SELECT
            ProcesseTmp.dt_inicio
        FROM
            tb_processo as ProcesseTmp  
            LEFT JOIN   tb_setor as SetorTmp ON SetorTmp.id_setor = ProcesseTmp.id_setor   
            LEFT JOIN   tb_lote_ticket as LoteTicketTmp ON LoteTicketTmp.id_lote_ticket = ProcesseTmp.id_lote_ticket   
            LEFT JOIN   tb_lote as LoteTmp ON LoteTmp.id_lote = LoteOrdemTmp.id_lote  
        WHERE
            LoteTmp.id_lote = Lote.id_lote AND 
            SetorTmp.id_setor = Setor.id_setor
        ORDER BY 
            ProcesseTmp.dt_inicio
        LIMIT 1
    ) as "Processe.dt_inicio",
    (
        SELECT
            ProcesseTmp.dt_inicio
        FROM
            tb_processo as ProcesseTmp  
            LEFT JOIN   tb_setor as SetorTmp ON SetorTmp.id_setor = ProcesseTmp.id_setor   
            LEFT JOIN   tb_lote_ticket as LoteTicketTmp ON LoteTicketTmp.id_lote_ticket = ProcesseTmp.id_lote_ticket   
            LEFT JOIN   tb_lote as LoteTmp ON LoteTmp.id_lote = LoteOrdemTmp.id_lote  
        WHERE
            LoteTmp.id_lote = Lote.id_lote AND 
            SetorTmp.id_setor = Setor.id_setor
        ORDER BY 
            ProcesseTmp.dt_inicio DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as "Processe.dt_final",
FROM 
    tb_mapa_producao as Processe  
    LEFT JOIN tb_setor as Setor ON Setor.id_setor = Processe.id_setor   
    LEFT JOIN tb_lote_producao_ordem_ticket as LoteTicket ON LoteTicket.id_lote_ticket = Processe.id_lote_ticket   
    LEFT JOIN tb_lote_producao as Lote ON Lote.id_lote = Lote.id_lote  
WHERE 
    Processe.dt_inicio  BETWEEN '09/09/2015 00:00:00' AND '14/10/2015 23:59:59'
    and 1=1
    and ( Processe.fl_desativado is false OR Processe.fl_desativado is null )
GROUP BY 
    Lote.id_lote, 
    Setor.ds_setor, 
    Setor.id_setor, 
ORDER BY 
    Lote.id_lote, 
    Setor.ds_setor, 
    Setor.id_setor,
```

#### Dados para teste

```
tb_lote
    id_lote     |   ds_lote
    1           |   teste1
    2           |   teste2

tb_lote_ticket
    id_lote_ticket  |   id_lote     |   nr_quantidade
    1               |   1           |   10
    2               |   1           |   10
    3               |   1           |   10
    4               |   1           |   10
    5               |   1           |   10
    6               |   1           |   10
    7               |   2           |   10
    8               |   2           |   10
    9               |   2           |   10
    10              |   2           |   10

tb_processo
    id_processo     |   id_lote_ticket  |   id_setor    |   dt_inicio
    1               |   1               |   3           |   2015-10-01 15:00:00
    2               |   2               |   3           |   2015-10-01 15:12:00
    3               |   3               |   3           |   2015-10-01 15:24:00
    4               |   4               |   4           |   2015-10-01 15:36:00
    5               |   5               |   4           |   2015-10-01 15:48:00
    6               |   6               |   4           |   2015-10-01 16:00:00
    7               |   7               |   6           |   2015-10-01 15:12:00
    8               |   8               |   6           |   2015-10-01 15:24:00
    9               |   9               |   6           |   2015-10-01 15:36:00
    10              |   10              |   6           |   2015-10-01 15:48:00
```

#### Resultado Esperado

```
id_lote     |   id_setor    |   dt_inicio               |   dt_final
1           |   3           |   2015-10-01 15:00:00     |   2015-10-01 15:24:00
1           |   4           |   2015-10-01 15:36:00     |   2015-10-01 16:00:00
2           |   6           |   2015-10-01 15:12:00     |   2015-10-01 15:48:00
```

Ou seja: *de cada lote, obter a data de início e fim de cada setor, sendo que a data de início corresponde ao primeiro processo do setor e a data fim corresponde ao último processo do setor*.

Comment: Está difícil de entender o problema. Vai ajudar a conseguir boas respostas de você mostrar exemplos de dados em todas as tabelas e o resultado esperado conforme os dados de exemplo. Outro ponto é que talvez uma query mais simples seja mais ineficiente que a tua original no teu cenário real. Será excessivamente trabalhoso, chato e eventualmente ingrato considerar este aspecto nas respostas. Se você nem sabe ainda o quanto sua query é ineficiente é porque eficiência não é um problema - eu tiraria este aspecto da questão.

Comment: Podemos dizer que *de cada lote, você quer a data de início e fim de cada setor, sendo que a data de início corresponde ao primeiro processo do setor e a data fim corresponde ao último processo do setor*?

Comment: @Caffé Exatamente isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert para a gente te ajudar, recomendo colocar a criação das tabelas e dados neste site http://sqlfiddle.com/, e passar a url para a gente. Ai conseguimos te ajudar, pois no teu exemplo acima falta a tabela tb_mapa_producao e tb_setor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Aí está:

```
select 
    lote_ticket.id_lote, processo.id_setor, 
    min(processo.dt_inicio) as dt_inicio, max(processo.dt_inicio) as dt_final
from
    tb_processo as processo join tb_lote_ticket as lote_ticket 
        on lote_ticket.id_lote_ticket = processo.id_lote_ticket
group by
    lote_ticket.id_lote, processo.id_setor
order by 
    lote_ticket.id_lote, processo.id_setor
```

Veja funcionano no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3966d/1/0).

## Explicação

Você fez duas subqueries que servem apenas para buscar a data de início e a data fim.

Sua primeira subquery traz a data de início pegando o primeiro registro. A segunda subquery é quase idêntica e traz a data fim pegando o primeiro registro da mesma query só que ordenada inversamente.

Ora, o que você fez foi reproduzir as funções de agregação **Min** e **Max**.

Minha query ficou mais simples porque eu usei estas funções internas do banco em vez de reproduzir o seu comportamento com subqueries.